SSH key works for FileZilla and Windows CMD, but not PuTTY
I upgraded Raspbian on my 6 Raspberry Pi units from Bullseye to Bookworm by:

Updating /etc/apt/sources.list.
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

I didn't change anything in the upgrade. The default was N to not change configs. Everything is still working as usually, but SSH is not.
Then when trying to SSH in, I get this error in PuTTY:

Restarting didn't fix it.
As a hail mary, I tried logging in with FileZilla using the exact same .ppk key, and it works fine!

I don't have sudo access with SFTP, so I can't change anything substantial, but that does give me some access to the box. I was hoping to get SSH working, and I don't have the password. When creating user accounts, I enabled SSH and gave each user a random password that I immediately removed so the only way in was the SSH key.
I also didn't touch PuTTY nor FileZilla. Both were configured and working with SSH keys prior to this change. Both are also targeting the pi user.
Here are the file permissions:


What can I do to regain access to my Raspberry Pi now that I'm in this strange predicament?
[EDIT] SSH even works from Windows 11! This is the first time I've ever used it without PuTTY. It seems to be a PuTTY issue, but I'd still like to solve it.

SSH works from Windows 11?  Well, that's a clear indication that the key is setup properly.  I'm guessing you're referring to the variation of OpenSSH that Microsoft has used.  Try using "ssh -v whatever", and scroll up and find the line that starts with "Server host key:".  Don't give us the full key (probably safe, but unnecessary), but do tell us what shows up next (maybe before the next colon), e.g. I see "debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:"  (I suspect that might be a type that your compiled version of PuTTY isn't supporting.)

@TOOGAM: this is a problem with the (a?) user=client key, not the host=server key. OP: do you have pageant running? If so putty will use key(s) from it, but I don't know if filezilla will; this might cause a different result.

It says SHA256. My PuTTY version is Release 0.70 (file config 0.12). PuTTY does say to use Pageant, but I don't have it running if it's a separate app. Both are hard-coded to use the same id-rsa.ppk key. I did zero configuration in Windows. It just works probably from where I placed the key.

You were right. I upgraded to Release 0.80 (file config 0.22), and it works now!

You may want to further update PuTTY to version 0.81 for the CVE-2024-31497 vulnerability fix if you use ECDSA keys, and replace any such keys that were ever used by PuTTY.

Ah! OpenSSH 8.8 (2021) up no longer supports the old SHA1-based ssh-rsa algorithm now requiring rsa-sha2-{256,512} instead, but PuTTY supports the rsa-sha2 algorithms only in 0.77 (2022) up, so that makes sense. @Ben: note the vulnerability is only for ECDSA keys using P-521, not the much more common P-256 and P-384.

I was using the "file config" rather than the registered version of PuTTY, but it's compiled from another source and can be behind the current version. Once 0.81 comes out, I'll switch to it. I'll need to update my private key. I think I made this one in 2008 back when I had a friend set up Gentoo on an old Pentium III!

@dave_thompson_085 I understand that (replying to your first comment). Having looked at your second comment mentioning rsa-sha2, I yield this opportunity to you. I suggest you make a proper "Answer" including the details, and then OP can officially "accept" an answer related to the question.  I do strongly suggest incorporating the advice of Ben Hutchison's comment.  Sawtaytoes: "registered version"? Not free? I haven't looked too much into PuTTY on RaspPi yet, but regular PuTTY (for PC) is just plain open source freeware, without a "registered" version.  Hope you didn't get scammed somehow!

Registry** version I mean, not Registered ;P.

You need to update the PuTTY version. OpenSSH no longer supports the old SHA1-based ssh-rsa algorithm: http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8
Thanks to @dave_thompson_085 for finding this info.
The change was made in 2021, and the PuTTY version you have, 0.70 is too old.
0.75 and newer are compatible with your Raspberry Pi on the latest OS:

Upgraded default SSH key fingerprint format to OpenSSH-style SHA-256.
Source: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/changes.html

